# SWIFT : How to Share multiple Photos or Video on Facebook using FBSDKShareKit?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-share, xcode11.3

I am using **FBSDKShareKit** to share **video** and **images** on **facebook**.

*Here is the code*:-

```
    if self.postObject.videoUrl.count > 0 {

            let content = ShareMediaContent()
            for VideoData in self.postObject.postedMedia {

                let video = ShareVideo.init(data: VideoData)
                content.media.append(video)
            }
            for thumb in self.postObject.postedVideoThumb {
                let photo = SharePhoto(image: thumb, userGenerated: true)
                content.media.append(photo)
            }
            let dialog = ShareDialog(fromViewController: self, content: content, delegate: self)
            print(dialog.canShow)
            dialog.show()

    }
```

But I am getting 
**print(dialog.canShow) as false**.

And the error I am getting in the "**didFailWithError**" delegate is:-

**" Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentValueKey={length = 1727854, bytes = 0x00000014 66747970 71742020 00000000 ... acdda1ed 0ae116c8 }, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Cannot share video data., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=data} "**

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I had this error after I notice that the native facebook app must be installed.

But now with some configuration (Facebook Developer) is not necessary to have the Facebook app installed (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)